# Not connecting to Wi-Fi on first boot only, after editing wpa_supplicant

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, wpa-supplicant

Raspberry Pi 4. So I have a python script (run at startup) with a GUI where it is possible to select a wifi network form a list and enter its password; such infos are saved to a file which will later (at startup) substitute the wpa_supplicant file. The system is then reboot (my python file does it), but when it is back on (and the entire wpa_supplicant gets updated) the Wi-Fi is not connected. It takes another reboot to get to Wi-Fi to successfully connect and work.
From various sources (stackoverflow and stackexchange) I was able to obtain and successfully use (kinda) the code below:

```
subprocess.check_output('sudo chmod 777 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf', shell= True)
```

(The line above is maybe necessary because my Pi is in read-only)

```
shutil.copyfile('/media/pi/ALLDATA/wpa_supplicant.conf', '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf')
```

(copy the file from a USB stick to the wpa_supplicant location)

```
os.system("sudo service networking restart")
```

(restart networking)

So the question is: why do I need a futher reboot (a total of two) after changing wpa_supplicant for the Wi-Fi to work?

EDIT: So to rephrase the question and get more help: I need to update the entire wpa_supplicant file with new Wi-Fi credentials every time someone enters them on a GUI (made with Qt). When someone enters the info on the GUI I automatically reboot the Pi4 and at startup substitute the wpa_supplicant file. It takes another reboot (the second) for the Wi-Fi credentials to be valid and the Wi-Fi to connect. Why?

Comment: Could you make this question clearer? The title isn't even a question, the description rambles whilst being unspecific ("kinda"). Ask the question properly, once time. Include your commented script. Rewrite everything and be concise.

Comment: There is a specific question (even with a question mark, mind you) and an EDIT further explaining the problem. Also I found an answer already (as seen in the answers below) involving systemctl and waiting longer for the wifi to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself: the reset method has to be systemctl wpa and dhcp (as seen here https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324155 ). Also Wi-Fi takes a second to connect after any boot sequence, so I just had to wait for it a bit longer.